# Proving that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ is bounded while $g(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$is not.

Tags: real-analysis

We have $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$$ and $$g(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$$ How can we ascertain whether $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$ or not? First let us take $y=ax$, where $a$ is an arbitrary constant. Then we have a dependence on $x$. We have boundedness. For both functions.

Both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equal to $0$ at $(0,0)$.

I have to prove that $f(x,y)$ is bounded in the whole of $\Bbb{R^2}$, but $g(x,y)$ is unbounded in every neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.

I don't know how to go about this. I've tried putting plugging in values and manipulation the expressions, but somehow I get the impression that if $f(x,y)$ is bounded, then $g(x,y)$ should be bounded too. Why such a massive different when we replace just a $y^4$ by a $y^6$?

Comment: To show that $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of the origin, note that $(x-y^2)^2\geq 0$, which implies that $x^2+y^4\geq 2{x}{y^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others noted, $(y^2-|x|)^2\geqslant0$ hence $2|x|y^2\leqslant x^2+y^4$, which implies that $|f(x,y)|\leqslant\frac12$ for every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$. On the other hand, $g(y^3,y)=\frac1{2y}$ for every $y\ne0$ hence $g$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $(0,0)$.